# How can I make a Log for exceptions using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am currently working on a database and need to document the zip codes of our customers, but I'm having a little bit of trouble developing a log in SQL, I want the exceptions to be picked up by Java and sent to a "Exceptions" table on SQL.

Any kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a considerably more complicated question than what it looks like at first blush.

Your first problem is how to get access to these exceptions in the first place.

Rather unfortunately, just about every tutorial (and many, *many* stack overflow answers. I try my best but can't catch all the abuse) have a copious amount of this incredibly bad code:

```
try {
   some stuff;
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have this in your code, **what you want is impossible, period**.

So step 1 is to go search for this pattern in your source code and get rid of it. The proper solution is, in order of preference:

1. Best solution is that all methods that throw (checked) exceptions they cannot handle **throw them onwards**. Your `public String readFile()` method should NOT try/catch that IOException, it should be declared as `public String readFile() throws IOException`. A method named 'readFile' should throw that, if it does not, you've messed up.
2. A distant second best solution is to wrap an exception. This becomes the best solution if the exception type is an implementation detail and not inherent in the method's name/types/documentation. A method named `readFile` obviously interacts with files (it'd be very badly named if it did not!), and any interaction with files naturally emits IOException. But if the method was named `readConfig` it's more nebulous, and it's up to you as API designer where it should (it probably should, but one can make an argument that one should be throwing ConfigException and not IOException). This looks like:

```
try {
    some stuff;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
}
```

Note the format! It *MUST* be of this form (where you pass the exception to the constructor of the new exception you throw), otherwise **what you want is impossible**.

3. Even more distant is that you log the exception and return something:

```
try {
    some stuff;
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.warn("Can't read config file {}", configPath, e);
}
```

Again, you MUST pass the exception to the log system or **what you want is impossible**.

Log systems in java are split into a 'front' and a 'back'. The front is how you log stuff (so the `log.warn` method here). The 'back' is where these logs go. If you want this stuff to go to the database, figure out what logging 'front' you are using (and if you aren't yet using anything, I suggest Flogger because it is the best API, or Slf4j because it is the most widely used. Your choice). Read the docs on how to set up your own custom logger so that you can write code where all these logs 'arrive', and then you can write your code to turn these into DB row inserts there.

4. However, not all exceptions are caught and logged like this. Instead, proper exception handling keeps throwing exceptions upwards and will eventually get caught all the way 'at the top', by whatever code invoked the entrypoint. Entrypoints are where your code begins to run, and it depends on what code you have as to what that might be: Writing webserver handlers? Then the entrypoint is the web framework that is invoking your `doGet()` method. Writing a plain jane java app? Then the entry point is the code baked into java that ends up invoking your `public static void main()` method. Fired up a thread? Then the entry point is the code baked into java's Thread class that ends up invoking your `run()` method. It depends on the framework as to how they deal with exceptions. Generally, frameworks log it to some logging thing, so read the docs and write a log handler for that framework so you can see them and write them to the DB.

For java's own stuff (both Thread's run and your main method), it's the thread's uncaught exception handler mechanism. So, register a default uncaught exception handler using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, so that you can write code that will be run anytime an exception is thrown *and* bubbles all the way to one of java's baked in entrypoint runners.

### Okay, now what?

So, you have written (probably in multiple places) code that runs when uncaught exceptions occur: Log handlers, and the default uncaught exception handler.

An exception consists of a type (e.g. IOException), a message, a stack trace, and a cause. The cause is, itself, an exception and can also have a cause. Thus you can have a chain of events: The disk is full, thus I cannot perform the SQL INSERT statement, thus the record of all transactions cannot be kept, thus this transfer of €10,- from Joe's balance to Jane's balance cannot be performed.

That would show up as a `BalanceTransferException` instance whose cause is a `TransactionLogException` whose cause is an `IOException` that has a message along the lines of 'disk full'.

And each exception in this chain has its own stacktrace, however, those stack traces all tend to end in the same lines.

(There is even a 5th element to an exception, which is a list of suppressed exceptions. But as the name suggests, these are rarely interesting, and you probably do not need to log these at all).

It's 2021. If you want to shove 20MB worth of text into a database row, just do it. Nothing is 'too big'.

So, what you want is: How do I turn an instance of an Exception into one, or perhaps a few, Strings which are then ready to insert into a DB? (You could, I guess, create a separate table for individual stacktrace lines, but that's overengineering things by a large margin).

These text lines are large, so you want a database engine that supports variable length strings. Fortunately, all except the most idiotically badly engineered databases make this easy, so just use `VARCHAR` as type (e.g. in postgres, where string storage is variable length anyway). If you're on one of those weirdo db designs, use a CLOB type.

To obtain these strings:

`e.printStackTrace()` is a reasonable solution (it does quite some 'nice' formatting). Note that the method name is a total lie, it doesn't print the stack trace, it prints much more (type, message, trace, and causal chain) but it can only write to printstreams. so let's use it:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
exception.printStackTrace(pw);
pw.close();
String blob = sw.toString();

// now save 'blob' in your log db. Probably include timestamp, that sounds useful.
```

### DBs?

I assume you already know how to write to DBs from java. If you don't, look up JDBI or JOOQ tutorials.

### But I really want to catch those `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` llines!

I said **impossible**, didn't I? Go back in there and fix that code. Your only alternative is to move away from the notion of 'capturing exceptions', and towards 'lets just assume this app never sends anything to system.err ever, so if anything appears there, neccessarily those are just stack traces emitted by folks who wrote horrible code'. Which you CAN do: `System.setErr` can be used to change what `System.err` goes to. You'd have to write a custom impl of a PrintStream which will just buffer all chars sent to it, until a newline symbol is sent, and then write the line into a db table. Unless you go out of your way to parse all this and reconstitute the exception (possible, but difficult), this isn't so much a 'table of exceptions thrown' as it is a 'table of lines that were otherwise heading out to the process error stream'.

That's a distant, *distant* plan Z. plan A is to just write proper code, which involves never writing `e.printStackTrace();` in a catch block. Even if so many SO answers and tutorials engage in this horribly boneheaded practice.

### It's too much!

I guess some ideas are to follow the causal chain first - usually the exception is far less interesting than the cause. So, keep invoking `.getCause()` until it returns null:

```
Throwable mostRelevant = exception;
while (true) {
   Throwable cause = mostRelevant.getCause();
   if (cause == null) break;
   mostRelevant = cause;
}
```

and log only that exception's type, message, and stack trace, so these 3 strings:

- `mostRelevant.getClass().getName()`
- `mostRelevant.getMessage()` (may be null!)
- `Arrays.toString(mostRelevant.getStackTrace())`

If you want to reduce even further, you'd have to try to write some intelligent guesstimates about which line(s) of that stack trace are actually interesting. But I'd just log it all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, about it being sort of impossible, my boss asked me for it and telling him I can't do it without even trying is out of the question, nevertheless, you helped me a lot.